# How to append to a list from a csv reading a column with operators appearing in line ; getting "invalid literal for float()" error

Tags: python

I am appending to a list from a csv which looks like this

`SampleA,Type,3.782*0.0627`

then `vals = line.split(',')`

So, I ve tried something like
`value = float(str(vals[2]))`
or
`value = float(vals[2])`

but I get errors like `ValueError: invalid literal for float(): 3.782*0.0627`

So what I want, is to basically store to `value = 0.237` ie the result of the mutlipication

TIA

Comment: Is that column always two numbers separated by an asterisk?

Comment: good point ; no, sometimes it is just one float, sometimes it needs to be two as the example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to execute the operation `3.782*0.0627` "manually".
You can do it like so:

```
value1, value2 = map(float, vals[2].split("*"))
value = value1 * value2
```

But if there is a possibility that you can encounter any other operation under `vals[2]` then you should implement a handling logic for every case.

Also, if you are parsing csv consider using [python standart csv library](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)

Answer (score 2):

You could calculate the float first.

```
floats = vals[2].split('*')
value = float(floats[0]) * float(floats[1])
```

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer doesn't handle the case that there is only one value, for that I would suggest (Python 3.8 or later)

```
from math import prod

value = prod(map(float, vals[2].split("*")))
```

Or similarly

```
from math import prod

value = prod(float(x) for x in vals[2].split("*"))
```